# Admin accounts unable to see plugins from external IP

Tags: plugins, admin

I have a bit of a strange issue here, please let me know if I explain this badly.

So I have created a new admin account ,for a remote developer, that has all the same permissions that I do.

When I logged in to test the account works, I can see all the plugins.

When my developer logs in from his office in another city,with the same account, he is unable to see the plugins.

The only thing I can think of is that maybe wordfence blocks certain things? I'm not 100% on what wordfence does by default.

If anyone needs more information let me know.